# From Excel to list of tuples

Tags: python, excel

I have an Excel (.xlsx) file that has two columns of phrases. For example:

```
John  I have a dog     
Mike  I need a cat
Nick  I go to school
```

I want to import it in Python and to get a list of tuples like:

```
[('John', 'I have a dog'), ('Mike', 'I need a cat'), ('Nick', 'I go to school'), ...]
```

What could I do?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far ? Why is there a parenthesis between `Nick` and `'I go to school` ?

Comment: That was a mistake, thanks, I have corrected it. I tried using pandas but I got a dataframe and not a list of tuples

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read the excel file using [`pd.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html). You need to care about the header is there are some or not.

As you said, it returns a dataframe. In my case, I have the following.

```
df = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
print(df)
#         name         message
# 0       John    I have a dog
# 1       Mike    I need a cat
# 2       Nick  I go to school
```

Then, it's possible to have the values of the dataframe using [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html). It return a `numpy` array.

If you want a list, we use the `numpy` method [`tolist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) to convert it as `list`:

```
out = df.to_numpy().tolist()
print(out)
# [['John', 'I have a dog'],
#  ['Mike', 'I need a cat'],
#  ['Nick', 'I go to school']]
```

As you can see, the output is a list of list. If you want a list of *tuples*, just cast them:

```
# for getting list of tuples
out = [tuple(elt) for elt in out]
print(out)
# [('John', 'I have a dog'), 
#  ('Mike', 'I need a cat'), 
#  ('Nick', 'I go to school')]
```

---

**Note**:
An older solution was to call [`values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) instead of `to_numpy()`. However, **the documentation clearly recommends using `to_numpy`** and forgive `values`.

Hope that helps !

Answer (score 4):

```
import pandas as pd    
file_path = r'filepath.xlsx'
xlsx = pd.read_excel(file_path)
names = xlsx.names    
scores = xlsx.scores    
my_list = [(name, score) for name in names for score in scores]   
print(my_list)
```

You need to modify file_path, name and score.
In addition, if you have not imported pandas before, then you need to execute pip install pandas in the terminal first

Answer (score 4):

So, you can use the pandas data frames to read and work with excel files very easily. 
The below solution will actually result in a list of lists. I hope it helps anyway. 
First response on StackOverflow and also I am not the most experienced programmer. ^^

```
df = pd.read_excel (r'PathOfExcelFile.xlsx')
print (df)
mylist = [df.columns.values.tolist()] + df.values.tolist()
print (mylist)
```

https://datatofish.com/read_excel/

https://datatofish.com/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-list/

Comment: `list` is a reserved keyword in python you cannot use `list` as a variable name. And your solution isn't complete.

Comment: @AvishkaDambawinna you definetly can. It is a class name. Python keywords are (at least for 3.7.3): `False`, `None`, `True`, `and`, `as`, `assert`, `async`, `await`, `break`, `class`, `continue`, `def`, `del`, `elif`, `else`, `except`, `finally`, `for`, `from`, `global`, `if`, `import`, `in`, `is`, `lambda`, `nonlocal`, `not`, `or`, `pass`, `raise`, `return`, `try`, `while`, `with`, `yield`. They were different for python2, e.g. `print` was a keyword (and is not anymore).

Comment: @БогданОпир, Of course, you can use them as a variable name but it isn't a good practice in coding.

Answer (score 4):

You need to [install](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/install.html#installing-from-pypi) and `import pandas` and need to install `xlrd` module

```
pip install pandas
pip install xlrd
```

then

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("dataset.xlsx", header=None)   #header=None means no header
mylist = list(map(tuple, df.to_numpy()))
#output
#[('John', '  I have a dog     '), ('Mike ', ' I need a cat'), ('Nick ', ' I go to school')]
```

---

**Explanation**:

[`.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) will read the excel into pandas dataframe,

```
df = pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx", header = None)

#        0                1
# 0  John        I have a dog
# 1  Mike        I need a cat
# 2  Nick        I go to school
```

Use `None` for the `header` parameter if there is no header. `header=None`

If header exists,

```
df = pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx")

#     Name        Status     <-headers
# 0  John     I have a dog
# 1  Mike     I need a cat
# 2  Nick     I go to school
```

[`to_numpy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy) Convert the DataFrame to a NumPy array. Using [`map`](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Map,_Filter,_Reduce) the item is sent to the function([`tuple()`](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/tuples.html)) as a parameter to convert each set of rows to tuples.

```
mylist = list(map(tuple, df.to_numpy()))
```

---

Refer:
[`pandas.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html), [`map`](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Map,_Filter,_Reduce)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html):

```py
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')

ws = wb.active
cells = ws['A1:B3']

l = []
for c1, c2 in cells:
    l.append((c1.value, c2.value))

print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of Pandas' [`to_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_records.html) function, which converts a DataFrame to a NumPy record array.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("db.xlsx", sheet_name="test", header=None)
results = list(df.to_records(index=False))

>>> print(results)
[('John', 'I have a dog'), ('Mike', 'I need a cat'), ('Nick', 'I go to school')]
```